# Import errors with WSGI, Flask, and Apache

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

Totally new to python-based web apps, so I'm somewhat lost. Here is my apache error:

```
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45] mod_wsgi (pid=23704): Target WSGI script '/home/http/public/hello/hello.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45] mod_wsgi (pid=23704): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/http/public/hello/hello.wsgi'.
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45]   File "/home/http/public/hello/hello.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45]     from hello import app as application
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45]   File "/home/http/public/hello/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45]     from flask import Flask
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45] ImportError: No module named 'flask'
[Wed May 08 22:41:47 2013] [error] [client 64.56.91.45] File does not exist: /home/http/public/favicon.ico
```

Apparently, it cannot find the `flask` module. I've looked this up, and it seems that most people get it to work by appending the project directory to the path, like so: (hello.wsgi)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/http/public/hello")
from hello import app as application
```

And here is hello.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Works great when ran as `python hello.py`, however, throws a 500 error when browsing to host/hello. Here's the Apache configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess hello user=http group=http threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /hello "/home/http/public/hello/hello.wsgi"

<Directory /home/http/public/hello/>
    WSGIProcessGroup hello
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm somewhat lost.

Comment: how did you install flask?  is it in a virtualenv?

Comment: Installed flask through pip: ```pip2 install flask```

Comment: But how many Python versions/installations do you have. Likely that mod_wsgi is built against a different version to where you are installing packages.

Comment: Oh goodness, I didn't think about the python versions. I just installed the python2 version of mod_wsgi and it works great. I must have overlooked that when installing it. Thanks! (ps: please make that an answer so I can give you credit. =))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mod_wsgi module is built against a specific Python version and can only work with that version. You cannot force it to use a different version. Thus if you have multiple versions installed, you need to make sure that you are installing your packages and running your code in development against the same version.

You can determine which Python version/installation mod_wsgi is using by running the test:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use