# Tensorflow import error on apache server Flask (wsgi) app

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, apache2, wsgi

I've run into a strange problem, I've installed **TensorFlow** on my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04.4) and I've a **Flask app** that runs without issues with `python3 __init__.py` and when I open another **ssh** session and make a request with curl it works as expected. But when I want to deploy the app and configure it with Apache, I get import error on TensorFlow in error log generated by **wsgi**.

Here is the apache configuration file **`flaskApp.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName IP_ADDRESS
    ServerAdmin EMAIL

    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskProcess threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskApp/flaskApp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/flaskApp/flaskApp/>
            WSGIProcessGroup flaskProcess
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flask-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/flask-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

WSGI File

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flaskApp/")
from flaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'someRandOmKey'
```

Notice I've not installed **Flask** on python2 just with python3 (3.7)

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import pickle

from flask import Flask, request
import cv2

# sys.path.insert(0,"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/")

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

There seems to be no problem with installation of TensorFlow (2.2.0) as it's running the script directly. But somehow WSGI won't find the module TensorFlow

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451509/import-errors-with-wsgi-flask-and-apache) seems to be relevant with mine but I've already installed TensorFlow for just `python3` and I'm using the shabang notation to use python3 on all python scripts

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Im having a similar issue

Comment: @jessica Not really but I thought of another work around. I hosted the app using NodeJS instead that would make a call to python script to run the model and produce result which I delegated to client. It introduced delay but worked. What problem are you facing?

Comment: I solved like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66234795/tensorflow-import-error-in-ec2-instance-with-flask-and-apache?noredirect=1#comment117145035_66234795