# Tensorflow Import error in Ec2 instance with Flask and Apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, tensorflow, flask, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host a web app on a Ec2 instace (no GPU, t2.,medium or t2.large) with Ubuntu 20.04 AMI, using the framework Flask. I am able to run the code locally, however I have problems when launching it on the server. I am able to launch a simple form in the server, but whenever I uncomment the `import tensforflow` line, I have the following error:

```
AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 9376:tid 140217758919744] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 9376:tid 140217758919744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I am in root, and when I open python3 in the terminal I am able to `import tensorflow` without problems, the issue happens with apache

```
/flaskapp$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> import cv2
```

I am using an instance with 2GB of RAM (also tried with a 4GB). I tried to do it within an environment but the same happened.

I put here the installations made in the instance:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt -y install python3-virtualenv
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
sudo apt-get -y install apache2
sudo apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 (without -py3 it says installs python2.7)
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-cpu  (had problems without -cpu)
sudo pip3 install opencv-python--headless  (had problems without headless)
sudo pip3 install flask
```

I basically followed the steps in [here](https://www.codementor.io/@jqn/deploy-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2-13hp1ilqy2), and then modify it to try to use a machine learning model.

```
mkdir ~/flaskapp
sudo ln -sT ~/flaskapp /var/www/html/flaskapp
sudo nano  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Add this in 000-default.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

<Directory flaskapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Add permission to a folder to be able to upload a file

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html/flaskapp/descargas
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www/html/flaskapp/descargas
```

Restart apache and see error log

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I don't know if has to do with the python version used in mod_wsgi, although seems to be the same 3.8 version. I don't know what could I do to change it either.

Some info of my python:

```
~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

:~$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

-------------- UPDATE-----------
I was able to solve this with the mentioned [here](https://asdkazmi.medium.com/deploying-flask-app-with-wsgi-and-apache-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-396607e0e40f) that requires an extra WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<Directory flaskapp>
   WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Possibly [see this](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api) as advised [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/476#issuecomment-544866603).

Comment: I already configured WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in the apache 000-default.conf configuration file.

Comment: @v25, yo are right, I had to add it twice as mentioned here https://asdkazmi.medium.com/deploying-flask-app-with-wsgi-and-apache-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-396607e0e40f        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        <Directory flaskapp>
             WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
             WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
             Order deny,allow
             Allow from all 
        </Directory>

Comment: Good stuff, I suggest answering your own question with that solution, as comments aren't greate for code.